# Keeping track of table accesses with multiple sub tables?

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

I'm basing this off the idea that you can use a proxy table in order to track table accesses as seen here: http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html

But what if my data structure wasn't a 1 dimensional table but looked something more like this:

```
table = {
    Nuts = 2;
    Fruits = {
        Apples = 5;
        Oranges = 3;
    };
}
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: The PiL goes on to to show that: _If we want to monitor several tables, we do not need a different metatable for each one_.

Comment: Also, do not use variable names like `table`.

Comment: First off I said "multiple SUB tables" as in they are nested, secondly the data structure was an example hence no need to rant about the variable name.

Comment: In the `newindex` metamethod, you can assign the `v` to proxy as well by doing `type(v) == 'table'`

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there any way to efficiently find all the parent tables if a child table encounters a change?